# Is this possible to get info about followers of instagram users?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I want to do simple dashboard for all my IG accounts.
I need to get all followers (usernames or id) who follow a certain user.
For example all followers of user foo.
I tried to do this with PHP and scraper but I can't do that. List of followers is generated dynamically via AJAX or something like that and we got only small amount of followers using this method.

Is this possible to do that? I've searched for PHP Instagram scrapers, there's 2 really good but I can't find something with that option. I want to do this without registering Instagram client because I need to get that information without credentials of a certain user.

Comment: [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) is what you are looking for, simply put in your access token and search the user by [his/her ID](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

Comment: OK, but need I the user's authorization to my app which I want to check? Sorry for noob questions. Still learning :)

Comment: The access token comes from your developer application, you should be able to get basic information using the [user endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) without authorisation depending if the account is private or public

Answer (score 0):

Using the Instagram API, you can only access the followers and following list of a logged in user(using access_token) , you cannot just any users followers, only the account you have access to.

Long time ago it was possible to access any user's followers, as of June 1st 2016, you can only access your followers and following (i.e the user you have login access to)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but must be any way to do that. I've seen a lot of tools that implemented this options.

Comment: instagram.com still allows you to access any user's followers/following, but official API does not anymore